# How to add image alt and title tags to wordpress images

Tags: image, wordpress

I'm trying to add an image alt and title text to each image in an image gallery in wordpress but can't seem to make it work. Here's my code:

```
<?php 

$events = get_group('Gallery');
foreach($events as $event){  

for($i=1;$i<4;$i++) {
if(empty($event['gallery_gallery_image_'.$i])) 
  continue
  ;
$image = $event['gallery_gallery_image_'.$i];
?>

<a href="<?php  echo $image[1]['o']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[1]['t']; ?>" /></a>

<?php } }?>
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

do you want to add them as static or dynamic ?

if it's static just add it after the tag

```
<img alt='xyz' title='abc' src="<?php echo $image[1]['t']; ?>
```

if not , just add the dynamic variable name like you did in your echo $image..

```
<a title="<?php  echo $image[1]['title']; ?>" href="<?php  echo $image[1]['o']; ?>"><img alt="<?php  echo $image[1]['alt']; ?>" src="<?php echo $image[1]['t']; ?>" /></a>
```

change $image[1]['alt'] && $image[1]['title']; (title & alt are the name of ur variables)

Comment: thanks for that

I do want to do it dynamically but still can't seem to get it to work - it's just delivers an empty alt and title

thanks

Comment: do you have your alt and title stored in ur variable $image ? if so do the following (see code above)

Comment: Hi not sure what u mean - stored in variable?

Comment: the $image variable is an array and it contains other info , you can see the content of that variable by doing print_r($image)

Comment: I see - all I seem to have is the image thumbnail and original, nothing else. How do I get the alt etc info into the var?

Comment: you will need to add them , do you have the alt and title stored somewhere in a database ? try to add them inside the function get_group() when you generated your events ...

Comment: i don't know the structures of your files but yes you need to add them in a way if u want to use them